# Informações do usuário logado não aparecem usando Firebase!

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, auth

Estou desenvolvendo um Web-app! No caso, um chat, porém, um chat com funções novas e legais!

***Estou fazendo apenas para aprendizado e diversão!***

No app, eu estou usando o Firebase, para criar Logins, Notificações etc!

A minha dúvida é: Não estou conseguindo mostrar as informações do usuário no site!

### Páginas

---

- **Index:**

```html
<div class="ui secondary  menu">
    <button onclick="window.location.href = '/';" class="ui inverted button">Home </button>

    <div class="right menu">
        <button id="sair-but" class="ui inverted button">Sair </button>
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<center>

    <div class="ui container">

        <div class="ui negative message" style="display: none;">
            <i class="close icon"></i>
            <div class="header">Você não está logado! </div>
            <p>Você precisa estar logado para enviar mensagens. </p>
        </div>

        <!-- Logue-se -->
        <div id="logue-se">
            <h1>Logue-se usando suas redes sociais:</h1>

            <!--  Botoes de login -->
            <button class="ui google plus button" id="login-but"><i class="google icon"></i> Google </button>

        </div>

        <div id="perfil">

            <img class="ui medium circular image" id="img-perfil" width="100px" height="100px">

            <h2 id="name"></h2>

        </div>
    </div>

</center>



<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<script src="login.js"></script>
```

---

- **Login.js:**

```js
  $("#login-but").click(function() {

      var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');

      firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
      firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
          if (result.credential) {
              // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
              var token = result.credential.accessToken;
              // ...
          }
          // The signed-in user info.
          var user = result.user;
      }).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          // The email of the user's account used.
          var email = error.email;
          // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
          var credential = error.credential;
          // ...
      });

  });

  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  if (user != null) {
      user.providerData.forEach(function(profile) {
          console.log("Sign-in provider: " + profile.providerId);
          console.log("  Provider-specific UID: " + profile.uid);
          console.log("  Name: " + profile.displayName);
          console.log("  Email: " + profile.email);
          console.log("  Photo URL: " + profile.photoURL);
      });
  }

  // Logout
  $("#sair-but").click(function() {
      firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
          // Sign-out successful.
      }, function(error) {
          // An error happened.
      });

  });
```

---

*Caso minha pergunta ainda não esteja muito clara, me avise por favor!*

Sempre quando eu tento pegar as informações do usuário, ele não dá erro. Simplsmente não faz nada! É como se o usuário não estivesse logado.

Eu quero fazer um sistema que quando o usuário não estiver logado! Aparece a div `logue-se`.

E se estiver logado, aparece a foto dele e o nome em baixo!

Comment: Dentro do seu ".catch(function(error) {..." coloque console.log(error), para podemos ver qual erro que o Firebase está retornando.

Comment: obrigado, eu não sabia, vou testaraqui

Comment: @lfarroco não da nenhum erro,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro tens que iniciar a aplicação com

```
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
  });
```

depois, tens que adicionar (pelo menos) o script de auth, visto que o estás a usar, em `firabse.auth()`.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

E, claro, não te esqueças de fazer referencia ao jQuery (no exemplo também não o tens). 
Finalmente, se meteres um `console.log(error)` na função de `.catch()` será facil continuares a perceber o que se passa :)

Comment: me desculpa, eu ocultei a inicialização por motivos de segurança

Comment: eu importei esse script ae,  e agora ta dando um erro no console: Uncaught Error: Firebase Service named 'auth' already registered.

Comment: @SampaioLeal isso quer dizer que estás a referir o `auth` duas vezes, tenta tirar a linha que tem o load do `firebase-auth.js`

Comment: eu nunca precisei colocar esse `firebase-auth.js` antes, e dava certo

Comment: @SampaioLeal - na documentação do Firebase diz que sim; Se estás a ter um erro, pode ser (por exemplo) porque a API da google já virá com esse plugin; Sendo assim, retira essa referencia (a referencia ao `firebase-auth.js`) e tenta.